# Why with Firefox you can not use arguments after opening a URL in applescript, shell script , Perl, ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, applescript, firefox-addon-sdk

with Safari or Chrome you can use an argument to open a URL

Example in Applescript in Safari

`Open location "https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/" & (the clipboard)`

The command lines of Firefox allow the opening url BUT WITHOUT ARGUMENT.
Is there a way to circumvent this failure by a script ???

AppleScript example:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    try
        open location "translate.google.com/#auto/en/" & (the clipboard)
    end try
end tell
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you show your code, please? Doesn't matter whether it's AppleScript, Python, Perl, Ruby or a shell script.

Comment: Whatever the script language (applescript, pyton, perl, ruby)
Find a way to pass arguments (like Chrome or Safari) to Firefox.

Tell application "Safari"
activate
try
Open location "https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/" & (the clipboard)
end try
end tell

Comment: Maybe Firefox simply doesn't know what to do with those arguments?

Comment: That part of the url is called the "[fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)", not "arguments".

Comment: If we were to speak of "fragment identifier" here we will speak of "tab" in the style
? Hl=fr&tab=wT.

Comment: This question should not be closed, it is a programing question.

Comment: @reinierpost: Agreed (note that the closure reason displayed reflects the majority of votes, but doesn't imply unanimity). However, the OP has since asked the same question again [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40726348/45375).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what do you say, since you do not understand the question, you can assume everything. If you don't understand, don't force yourself to invent answers. The script presented in applescript works very well for Safari.
The question is simple why with Firefox one can not complete command line with an argument url request. So example that works with Safari or Chrome:

```
*Open location "https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/" & (the clipboard)*
```

Here the argument is the clipboard that we have of course previously filled with text to translate.

There may be no reason why it works with Firefox. Especially remember that we are talking about Firefox. The script in applescript for Safari works

```
**Tell application "Safari"
activate
try
Open location "https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/" & (the clipboard)
end try
end tell**
```

**This is the method that works for Firefox. This is not the fastest, because you must first format the text if you want the entire content of the ClipBoard. I have to create the service in Automator without input for it to be in general, applicable everywhere.**

In Firefox the problem, which does not exist with Safari or Chrome, is when we call "translate.google.com" and we associate the ClipBoard to it, the text is not formatted on arrival and causes Of the errors 404. So if you do the maneuver in 2 steps of course there is no problem, open the page "translate.google.com" menu edit and paste.

```
[![** 
on run {input, parameters}
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "c" using command down
        end tell
    tell application "Applications/Firefox.app" to activate
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Firefox"
        set frontmost to true
        set sentence to text of (the clipboard)
        set thesentences to paragraphs of sentence
        set thenewsentences to thesentences as string
        set the clipboard to thenewsentences
        keystroke "t" using command down
        keystroke "https://translate.google.com/#auto/fr/" & (the clipboard) & return
    end tell
    end run
```

**][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX9d8.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX9d8.png)

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the question is -- it would help a lot if you'd include

1. Exactly what you're doing (in this case, what's in the clipboard is critical)
2. What you expect to happen
3. What's actually happening

For this answer, I'm going to assume you have some sort of non-English text in the clipboard, and you want to use Google translate to translate it to English. In this case, what you have should work as long as the contents of the clipboard are in the right format. This script, for example, will open a Safari window translating French to English:

```
set the clipboard to "Où sont les neiges d'antan"

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    try
        open location "translate.google.com/#auto/en/" & (the clipboard)
    end try
end tell
```

I don't really know what's going wrong for you, but one possibility is that what's in the clipboard is not plain text, but some sort of formatted text (rtf, html, or something like that), and the formatting is getting included along with the text. In this case, using `(the clipboard as text)` might solve it. Or not. I'd need more information to tell what's actually going on.